# git amend: Commit not amended

Tags: git, git-amend

I see a bit strange behavior with Git.

So I have a feature branch locally, say F1, and I add a commit, C1, to it. I push it to repo, get reviews and finally merge to master. So master has my commit C1 on top.

Then I realized that some changes in C1 are not needed. So I created another feature branch, say F2, from latest in master. Fortunately commit C1 is still at top. So I amended C1 itself, and changed the commit message with

> 'git commit --amend -m "new message"

pushed the branch, got it reviewed, got it merged to master.

I was expecting C1 to be still at top in master, with amended commit message. But it's not and new commit is on the top with new commit message, with C1 at position 2.

Is this 'amend' behaviour as expected?

Comment: They're _different_ commits. You haven't really "changed the commit message", you've created a new commit with the same changes but a different message. So yes, that's to be expected.

Comment: This question may seem funny to those familiar with Git, but IMHO it is absolutely a legitimate question to those who are still learning. (Isn't everyone always still learning something? It's kind of the point of this site.) I think the DVs here are unfortunate since this question is by no means "bad". In fact, there's a hidden problem implied in the question that may be helpful to address.

Comment: Note that the verb *amend* in `git commit --amend` is a lie. It's a *strategic* lie that's meant to be useful and informative, but you must remember that it's not true. Commits are immutable, and `git commit --amend` doesn't amend one: it makes a new one that you'd like people to use *instead of* the original. Whether and when people will actually do that is the key.

Comment: @torek, when used  with local branch, I have always seen it amending commit on top.  I need to check again, but it makes things quite confusing.

Comment: Look at the hash IDs, which are the true names of the commits. They *change*. Git didn't modify the existing commit (which would leave the hash ID alone). Git *kicked the existing commit off the end of the branch* and put a *different* commit on the end. The commit didn't get amended, but some notion of "the branch" did. The problem is that "the branch" is a very slippery phrase in Git. See [What exactly do we mean by branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happened is because you amended your commit `C1` *after* you had already merged it into `master`. Once a commit lands on a remote branch, (in this case `master`), the only way to *remove* a commit on `master` would be to rewrite the `master` branch and force push it. This is generally frowned upon for shared branches such as `master`, so instead you need to merge in another commit. Had you amended your commit *before* merging it into `master`, then it would have worked as you expected.

So that answers your question, but as an important side note, I'm concerned about this statement:

> Then I realized that some changes in C1 are not needed.

I urge you to look at the updated `master` with your new amended commit to make sure you actually accomplished your goal. The fact that you attempted to "remove" something instead of "adding" more things means it's likely you didn't succeed in doing it. Here's why:

Suppose you added things A and B in commit `C1`, but then decided you only wanted to add A. The `master` branch has `C1` which has both A and B. Now locally, you amended commit `C1` to make `C1'` which only has A. When you merge that into `master` it might just do nothing, since `master` already has A, and there is nothing in `C1'` that says to "delete B". If you discover this is what happened, then make sure to start with the latest `master` and "delete B" in another, new, (third) commit.